# Weird mime types of objects uploaded/downloaded to/from S3

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm working on a Lambda that fetches csv.gz files, unzips them and uploads them to S3 buckets. Evertyhing is working fine, however when I'm trying to download files, they have messed up mime types, doesn't matter if it's set in S3 Object metadata or not.

For example, for object that has Metadata equal to:

`Content-Type=text/csv
Content-Encoding=utf-8`

downloaded file returns following after running `file -i test.csv` command:

`test.csv: application/x-gzip; charset=binary`

So as you can see, totally different to what is specified in bucket.

I tried implementing my script both in Node and Python, with both specifying metadata and skipping those and both have the same problems and I'm out if ideas what might be causing this behavior. I would appreciate any hints or ideas on what might be the cause of the problem.

Regards

Comment: Did you check if the file was really decompressed? Can you view it like normal text file?

Comment: Yes, I have no problem opening it as a csv e.g. using LibreOffice Calc, or from Python script, however if I try to open it with Google Sheets, it just doesn't work as intended.

Comment: If the `file` utility is detecting the content as `application/x-gzip; charset=binary` then the object's `Content-Type: text/csv` as shown may actually be correct, but the `Content-Encoding` is wrong.  It should be stored as `Content-Encoding: gzip`.  `utf8` is not a valid value for the `Content-Encoding` header.  The only valid values are `gzip`, `compress`, `deflate`, `br`, and `identity`.  `Content-Encoding: identity` is equivalent to the header being entirely absent.   But if you are uncompressing the gz file, you need to use `file` on the result,  not the source.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot for explanation on Content-Encoding. I'm not sure I understand the second part - the `file -i` is applied to the uncompressed .gz file, which can be viewed in e.g. LibreOffice.

Comment: If `file -i` is returning `application/x-gzip; charset=binary` on a file that you believe you have already decompressed, then either you didn't actually decompress it, or the file was actually gzipped *twice* when you originally got it, so you undid the outer layer but not the inner layer... which would be wrong on the part of whoever is sourcing the files, but not impossible to do.